# UIView background color Animation with different color

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the background color of the `UIVIew` with animation and a different color in the cycle. But color is not changing.
Here is my code :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: self.getRedComponant(), green: self.getGreenComponant(), blue: self.getBlueComponant(), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
        }, completion:nil)
```

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: In which method of which file is this code located?

Comment: In initWIthNibName method and in UIView type file, I have written this method

Comment: What is `getRedComponant` and so on? You’ve left out a lot of code here. Please give all the information necessary.

Comment: func getRedComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;
    }
    
    func getBlueComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;
    }
    
    func getGreenComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;
    }

Comment: Do you want a different color each 0.6 sec?

Comment: Exactly, I what same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.repeat` doesn't execute the `getColorComponent()` every time it repeats, instead you could add a Timer

This works for me :

```
 var timer = Timer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0,  animations: {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: self.getRedComponant(), green: self.getGreenComponant(), blue: self.getBlueComponant(), alpha: 1)

            }, completion:nil)
        })
    }

    func getRedComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;


    }
    func getBlueComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;

    }
    func getGreenComponant() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks.
This code is working for change background.But I want to flash effect also.

Comment: Just change withTimeInterval: 1.0 to 0.2 for example in Timer

Comment: Yeah it works for me. Thanks Dude. But I want to more enhance Like in "Fanpictor" app.

Comment: By more enhance you mean faster? If so you can make it 0.05 or so instead of 0.2

Comment: Not faster but more smooth.

Comment: Change UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6 to 0.2 and withTimeInterval: to 0.2 let me know if it did it

Comment: Thanks dude for helping me. But can you please have a look at the "Fanpictor" app

Comment: Share a link to an example

Comment: @Kunwar , There is couple of options in the App, just play with withDuration and withTimeInterval until it looks how you want it. If I answered your original question please approve my answer

Comment: Approved @vadim F.